# Most efficient way to get nested documents at a specific level in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Considering the following structure:

```
      {
      "name": "CatA",
      "subcategories" : [
         {
         "name" : "SubCatA",
         "subcategories" : [
            {
            "name" : "SubSubCatA",
            "subcategories" : [
                {
                "name" : "SubSubSubCatA",
                "subcategories" : [
                ]
            }
         ]}]}]}
```

What is the best way to get all subcategories of, say, Level 3?

This works:

```
    db.Categories.aggregate(
        {$unwind: '$subcategories'},
        {$unwind: '$subcategories.subcategories'},
        {$unwind: '$subcategories.subcategories.subcategories'},
        {$project : { subcategories : "$subcategories.subcategories.subcategories" }}
    )
```

Is it the most efficient way to do it?